# How can I use Case satement in CTE tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I want use case in cte with this code :

```
Declare @DefinitionType Int = 1
;With Res
As
(
    Case @DefinitionType
        When 1 Then (Select [ActionId], [Title] From Actions)
        When 2 Then (Select [AreaId], [Title] From Areas)
        Else (Select [ContractorScopeId], [Title] From ContractorScopes)
    End
)
Select * From Res
```

That error is :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'.

How can I use Case satement in CTE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

If the columns are of compatible datatypes you can do

```
DECLARE @DefinitionType INT = 1;

WITH Res
     AS (SELECT [ActionId],
                [Title]
         FROM   Actions
         WHERE  @DefinitionType = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [AreaId],
                [Title]
         FROM   Areas
         WHERE  @DefinitionType = 2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [ContractorScopeId],
                [Title]
         FROM   ContractorScopes
         WHERE  @DefinitionType = 3)
SELECT *
FROM   Res
```